# react router dom fallback route with no layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following routes

```
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
     <Layout>
         <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
         <Route exact path='/players' component={Players} />
         <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
     </Layout>
     <Route component={ErrorPage} />
  </Switch>
```

The pages working fine, but it never falls to the error page,
it just displays the blank layout with no content

I want both the login page and error page has no layout, how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

For your specific usecase, don`t define layout component in Router. Create custom router for each component, for each component definition render layout except login and error page. You can refer to below url for more information
https://simonsmith.io/reusing-layouts-in-react-router-4/